# List the employees whose name starts with 'S' and ends with 'S'?

Tags: sql, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I know the SQL LIKE statement.

I want to implement SQL LIKE statement in Informatica.

The goal is list all the employees whose name starts with 'S' and ends with 'S'.

```
select ENAME from EMP where ENAME LIKE ('S%') and ENAME LIKE('%S');
```

Comment: The SQL statement would be: `ename like 'S%S'`.  I removed the MySQL and Oracle tags, because you seem to want an answer for Informatica.

Comment: i think thats what i asked in my question? @gordon linoff

Comment: @GordonLinoff For completeness, `ename like 'S%S' or ename = 'S'`. Some people use only initials in a "name" field, even if given explicit instructions to enter a name, and a plain "S" is matched by the OP's query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Informatica does not have a LIKE equivalent available. You can use REG_MATCH and insert in a regular expression that will match for starts with S and ends with S. Example Below:

```
REG_MATCH(ENAME,'[S^]+\w+[S$]')
```

RegExr Link: http://regexr.com/3b17b

Comment: Unless Informatica uses a completely different regex syntax than RegExr (and in that case, why link to RegExr?), this does not mean what you think it means. `[S^]` means "either `S` or `^`", not "`S` at the start of the text". Similar for `[S$]`. And `\w` does not mean "any character". A notable character that is not in `\w` but typically appears in names is the space character.

Comment: To add to @hvd's comment, Informatica does use Perl-like regular expressions, so you probably want '^S+\w+S$' to get the desired results.